# Is this a paypal bug, or is this just fantasy?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, paypal

An odd one this!  We have taken around 50 online event bookings today with no trouble, except for one.

We happened to notice that one contribution for £300 was showing as complete, but in fact the transaction at PayPal (using Website Payments Pro) was for £0.

The contribution has been set to the 'Accounts Receivable' Account, rather than the Payment Processor Account.

A **submit credit card payment** link has appeared, so Civi seems to know something is up, but to all intents and purposes the transaction appears successful so it was only by chance that we noticed.  Is this a bug, or have I missed some intended behaviour?

Thank you!

[image: Credit Card Payment Screen]

Comment: Ahh! Can you still replicate using same price combination?

Comment: @PradeepNayak No - each price option can only be sold once and then appears as 'sold out', so I can't buy it again (this is intentional - this is for stand booking at a conference trade show), and there were 40+ transactions after this for different stands which all went through fine!

Answer (score 2):

We have got to the bottom of this - due to an unforseen combination of selections, the customer's basket value at the time of transaction was indeed £0. The £300 item was added later.